About the reduction type of the Kodaira symbol of elliptic curves defined over p-adic local fields
Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $K$. Tate's algorithm can be used to compute the Kodaira symbol of the reduction type of $E$.
However, I can't relate the Kodaira symbol to the reduction type (good, split multiplication, non-split multipicative, ...) of $E$. Is there any references about it, or can you explain it?

The Kodaira symbol characterises the geometry of the special fibre, that is the structure over the algebraically closed field $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$. Good reduction means type I${}_0$, multiplicative reduction means I${}_n$ with $n\geq 1$ and additive reduction is all other symbols.
The question of whether the multiplicative reduction is split or not depends on the fibre over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e., are the tangents at the singular point defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or over the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. So the Kodaira symbol cannot see that. Tate's algorithm calculates other invariants and you can read it up in Step 7 (Subprocedure) in Silverman's "Advanced Topics..." in section IV.9.
However using Tate's algorithm to determine the reduction type is going very much too far. Proposition VII.5.1 in Silverman "The Arithmetic..." tells you how to detect if good, multiplicative or additive. Split or non-split can also be detected on the coefficients of the equation: See Lemma V.5.2 and Theorem V.5.3 in advanced Silverman.
In practice sagemath has ".has_split_multiplicative_reduction" and similar. They use pari's Tate algorithm. You could also test if the conductor is once, not or more often divisible by $p$ for the type and check $a_p$ to see if it is split or non-split. However I highly recommend learning first how to do this by hand with the above references.
